# Probability distribution in phase space and Liouville's theorem?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, probability, phase-space

We can define a probability distribution over phase space (say 1D) $\rho(x,p)$ such that, for example,
$$\langle x\rangle = \int x \rho(x,p) dxdp$$ etc.

It can be shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29) that such a distribution satisfies (analogously to fluid dynamics) $$\frac{d\rho}{dt} = 0$$ and therefore $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = - \{\rho, H\} $$ where the term on the right is a [Poisson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) and $H$ is the Hamiltonian.

Now,  shouldn't $\frac{d\rho}{dt} = 0$ imply that $\rho=$ constant?
But surely $\rho$ must have some sort of time/spatial dependence to satisfy the second equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, keep in mind this :

Let us considere a $f$ function depending on a single variable $x$. Then, you have the following implication :

$$\forall x,\;\frac{df}{dx}(x)=0 \Rightarrow f(x)=c^{st}\; (\text{regarding}\;x) $$

i.e. $f$ ***does not explictly depend on*** $x$

If now $f$ depends on a set of $n$ ***independant*** variables $(x_i)_{i\in[1..n]}$, you have :

$$\forall i,\forall(x_1...x_n)\; \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_1...x_n)=0 \Rightarrow f(x_1...x_n)=c^{st}\; \text{regarding}\;x_i$$

i.e. $f$ is only ***explictly depending*** on $n-1$ variables : $(x_1...x_{i-1}\,x_{i+1}...x_n)$

Now, if $f$ depends on a set of $n$ variables which are ***depending on a parameter*** $t$ : $(x_1(t)...x_n(t))$, then what as been said before is no longer true.

In such case, you have to follow a [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to perform a derivative in respect to $t$. In particular :

$$\frac{df}{dt}(x_1(t)...x_n(t))=0\nRightarrow f\; \text{is a constant regarding any}\;x_i(t)$$

of course. But,

$$\frac{df}{dt}(x_1(t)...x_n(t))=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{\
dx_i}{dt}=0\Rightarrow f\; \text{is a constant regarding}\;t$$

i.e. $f$ is "**conserved**" in respect of $t$.

Finally, for completeness, if now $f$ ***explictly depends*** on the parameter $t$, i.e. $f(x_1(t)...x_n(t),t)$, then :

$$\frac{df}{dt}(x_1(t)...x_n(t),t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{\
dx_i}{dt}=0\\\Rightarrow f\; \text{is globally a constant regarding}\;t$$

i.e. $f$ is "**conserved**" in respect of $t$ again. But, a priori $f$ ***still does explictly depend on $t$*** because in that case you must verify the indentity :

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\frac{\
dx_i}{dt}\neq 0$$

In conclusion, all of this shows that $\frac{df}{dt}=0$ for a multi-variable dependent function $f$ means only that the growth rate of $f$ in respect of $t$ is zero but does not mean that $f$ does not explictly depend on $t$.

Comment: Thanks.
So, say, in fluid dynamics $\frac{d\rho}{dt} = 0 $where $\rho$ is the density.
Does this mean:
1. The density of the fluid is a constant, $\rho = constant$

2. The density of a fluid has a spatial dependence but remains constant in time, $\rho = \rho(\mathbf{r})$

Comment: Regarding what has been said before, it's answer 1. $\frac{d\rho}{dt}=0$ means that $\rho$ is a "constant" in a sense that its growth rate $\frac{d\rho}{dt}$ regarding $t$ is zero. BUT, $\rho$ still explictly dependent on $\mathbf{r}$ and $t$ a priori!

Answer (score 3):

What is meant is that
$$\frac{d\rho(q(t), p(t), t)}{dt} = 0$$
when $q,p$ are solutions to Hamilton's equations. While it is notationally convenient and space-saving to not write everything out in this detail, it is as you noted confusing. This particular confusion actually has a name -- it's the *first fundamental confusion of calculus*. (There's a second fundamental confusion, too.)

You can formulate Hamiltonian mechanics coordinate-freely, and then there will be no ambiguity, but this requires some machinery (but the proof of Liouville's theorem is very neat in this formulation). Vladimir Arnold's book *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* will show you how.

Comment: but still shouldn't it be a constant?

Comment: It's constant along the path taken by the system.

Comment: Constant $\rho$ is a stable solution, but so is any function of Hamiltonian value $\rho(q,p) = f(H(q,p))$. Since Ham. value is constant in time, so is $\rho$ for given trajectory, but $\rho(q,p)$ is not constant throughout the phase space.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaking with the meaning of the total time derivative $\frac{d}{dt}$.

Actually,
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt}=\partial_t \rho + \{\rho,H\}=0
$$
is nothing but a ***conservation law***, or a [***continuity equation***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation) for the phase space density $\rho$. Actually, $\frac{d\rho}{dt}=0$ does not imply that $\rho$ is constant simply because $\rho$ is a *field* depending on several variables:
$$\rho\equiv\rho(q(t),p(t),t)$$
Thus, one can read from the equation the $\partial_t \rho$ term must exactly compensate the $\{\rho,H\}$ term at any point $(q,p)$ of the phase space, for each instant $t$. So, $\rho$ **must be** a function of $q$, $p$ and $t$ at the same time to be conserved.

Therefore, $\rho$ can't be a constant.

If you are more familiar with fluid-dynamics, you have a direct analogy with the [material derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative), which is nothing but a [total derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative).

For more completeness, one can write :
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt}=\partial_t \rho +\mathbf{X}_H\cdot\mathbf{\nabla}\rho
$$

where $\mathbf{X}_H=\left[\begin{array}\\\dot{q}\\\dot{p}\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}\\\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\\-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}\end{array}\right]$ is the Hamiltonian flow.

Comment: in fluid dynamics then, is incompressible flow usually associated with $\frac{d\rho}{dt} = 0$ ? Does this mean that the density is constant or that it has a non-varying spatial profile?

Comment: Hmm ok, I think you are mistaking between the different features again. In fluid-dynamics, the conservation of the mass gives you $\frac{d\rho}{dt}=\partial_t \rho+\nabla(\rho\mathbf{v})=0$. If you know that your fluid is incompressible, then for a homogene fluid you will have $\rho$ constant (i.e. independant from $\vec{r}$ and $t$) , leading thus to $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}=0$ from the conservation law.

Comment: regarding your answer:
You say that $\rho$ has to be conserved: doesn't this mean that it has to have the same numerical value at time progresses? How can a function satisfy this condition unless it is a constant?

Comment: See new answer for more comments.